# MeteorJS & ReactJS: Customizing parent and child re-renders?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

So, essentially, I have one parent component that has several child components. Currently, when I change the value of one child component the entire parent rerenders (i.e. click 'change colour' on one of the child components in a list of components).

I am using TrackerReact to handle this reactivity from my mongoDB database.

However, the major drawback to TrackerReact is it tends to re-render the entire parent element... I was hoping I could do something like:

If I am adding more items to the list, re-render the parent push all the child items down the list, otherwise, if I change the colour of the child, do not re-render the parent, just that child.

I was thinking `shouldComponentUpdate` on the parent, might work, with `forceUpdate()` for handling new children being added to the list?

But now I'm thinking I should dive into Meteor/Redux with https://atmospherejs.com/samy/redux-middlewares and then be able to control the entire store reactively.

I was also thinking I could handle everything with JQuery, but this isn't every DRY...

So, before I jump in, I thought I would post this general question about proceeding with customizing re-rendering / reactivity inside Meteor and React

Comment: Have you taken a look at this; https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution in the React way, then yes you should definitely use `shouldComponentUpdate` in the parent component. You shouldn't need to use `forceUpdate` if you are checking new data against old data in the `shouldComponentUpdate` function.